# Image is clickable even outside of the designated area - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Not sure where did I messed it up. Seems i can click the image that's pointing to index even on the left of the image, as shown in the image below.

[![img example][1]][1]

```
<section id="header">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="resources/logo-blue.png" class="Logo" alt="Logo"></a>
    [...] 
    </div>
</section>
```

and CSS:

```
.Logo {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
max-width: 100px;
max-height: 100px;
padding-left: 40%;
}
```

I know this might be a very basic question but this is my first major project, would really appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: What do you think `padding-left: 40%;` means?

Comment: my intention using padding was to move the content a bit on the right side and make the space before simply blank instead of having the action also on the empty space.

Comment: remove padding and add `transform: translateX(-40%);`

Comment: the `padding-left` property is the clickable area of the right side of image. remove `padding-left` and try to use `margin-left` property.

Comment: Padding adds spacing inside the container, which includes the clickable area of the anchor tag. Use margin instead which is for outside spacing.

Answer (score 2):

To make the clickable area of the link match the visible area of the logo, you should adjust the anchor tag's size and possibly its display properties.

I've made an example for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .LogoContainer {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            max-width: 100px;
            max-height: 100px;
        }

        .LogoContainer a {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="header">
        <div class="LogoContainer">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="resources/logo-blue.png" class="Logo" alt="Logo"></a>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, I added a new div element with the class LogoContainer that wraps the anchor () element and the logo image. The CSS for .LogoContainer a sets the anchor to display: block; and text-align: center;, making it cover only the visible area of the logo.

Good luck in your learning! :)

Comment: I think i messed up pretty bad, even while using your code I still get into the same issue. Head is same as I was using, but this for sure changed something in my code, as hight is different, but the space on the left of the image is still clickable. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the image clickable you can use

```html
<img href="https://quickmash.github.io" alt="LOGO" title="Logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTSR_CW2U0kVm052RqGCkF7hZkwYau9_Xu9oQ&usqp=CAU">
```

Just use your css with it and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all answering. Because of a mix of info i got from all your comments, i found what i've done wrong. I was using padding for image, **instead i used the margin for container and this solved my issue**. Not sure if it's the best solution long term, but it does the job for me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would highly recommend you to learn css bootstrap with it, it makes your pages responsive, because yes, you now see that it's working just fine but if for better web pages responsivness is a must! Good luck !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
padding-left: 40%;
```

Means that the image will be padded. So, if you have a click event listener on the image, then it will be triggered even if you click on the padding. Try

```
margin-left: 40%;
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `padding-left` with `margin-left` in `.logo` so that the space do not be counted as `<a>` tag.